# What are the correct names of twig files for image formatters of fields that reference media

Tags: media

I am a beginner and working for an improvement in D10 site. I want to create an image formatter for a field_gallery that exist in a few content types.

So I created a file field--node--field-gallery.html.twig that loops in items and adds the desired classes (it works). And then I created two files.
image-formatter--media--gallery--thumbnail.html.twig
image-formatter--media--gallery.html.twig

The *-thumnail.html.twig seems to work only in views where there is selected the thumnail format. But I want to work also in the full content view and the second file is not working.
What should be the correct name to work in the full content view and please explain the naming convention for full view or teaser or any view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you not enabled Twig debugging? That will show the template name hints in HTML comments.

Comment: How do I enable twig debugging?

Comment: OK. I found this video and is very helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ei2UWj5qwJc. Thank you